# change focus on parent div on focus of child href element using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div structure as below.

```
    <div class="class1">

        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="class2">

        </a>

   </div>
```

So on **focus** of **href**, may I know how we can **add** a **class** to **div**(that is parent of href) using angular js

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two directives. [data-ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)   and [data-ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<div class="class1" data-ng-class="{'className' : applyClass == true}">

   <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="class2" data-ng-focus="applyClass=true"></a>

</div>
```

Please don't forget to mention this varibale false in your controller first.

`$scope.applyClass = false;`

Or you can even use

```
<div class="class1" data-ng-init="applyClass = false" data-ng-class="{'className' : applyClass == true}">
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer Vineet, let me check :)